# how to effectively implement ViewPager with different fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So far I have only implemented ViewPager with one type of fragment.
Now I want to add navigation tabs and be able to slide sideways from fragment of type A to fragment of type B .  Do I need to contain both types of fragments in one activity ? If so , does it matter which fragment will have the view pager?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the fragments contain the `ViewPager`. That would be contained in this case in your activity. The navigation tabs sit above the `Viewager`. Look at this tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip . You can specify what fragments go in the `ViewPager` in the `getItem` method of a `FragmentPagerAdater`.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment =null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = fragment1.newInstance();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = fragment2.newInstance();
            break;              
        case 2:
            fragment = fragment3.newInstance();
            break;          }
    return fragment;    
}
```

Comment: what 'position' options would there be ? Is it the number of navigation tabs?

Thanks!

Comment: The `position` is the position of the whatever fragment in the `ViewPager`. Say you had three fragments and the last one was about bears then when   `position` is 3 you would return `BearFragment,newInstance()`.

Comment: does the getCount() method determine the number of positions? Or it is just the total quantity of fragments in a particular activity?

Comment: Yeah, it returns the number of fragments you'll be using. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getCount()